# How find $a,b\in\mathbb R$ if are given the matrices $AB$ and $BA$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Question:**

> Let $A_{4\times 3},B_{3\times 4}$ be real matrices such that $$BA=\begin{bmatrix}
> -9&-20&-35\\
> 2&5&7\\
> 2&4&8
> \end{bmatrix},\ AB=\begin{bmatrix}
> 9a-14&0&9a-15&18a-32\\
> 6a+2b-9&1&6a+3b-9&12a+4b-19\\
> -2a+2&0&-2a+3&-4a+4\\
> -3a+6&0&-3a+6&-6a+14
> \end{bmatrix}.
> $$
>   Find $a,b$.

Now to find $a$ note that $$\mathrm{Tr}{(AB)}=\mathrm{Tr}{(BA)}\Longrightarrow -9+5+8=9a-14+1-2a+3-6a+14\Longrightarrow a=0.$$
But for $b$ I can't see how to find it.

Thank you

Comment: I have no idea. May be conidering the partitions of $A,B$ helps you.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but how can $(AB)^T$ = $(BA)^T$ when one is 4x4 and one is 3x3

Comment: @Nic: Tr means Trace, not Transpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said because of $\operatorname{Tr}(BA)=\operatorname{Tr}(AB)$ we get $a=0$. After that you can substitute $a=0$ into to matrix $AB$.

From here after the substitution you get the same $AB$ and $BA$ matrices, like in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/731349/given-ba-find-ab?rq=1). So from this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/732396/153012) we could get that $b=0$.

Put is all together the solution is $a=b=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\lambda\ne0$ be an eigenvalue of $AB$, that is, $ABv=\lambda v$ for some $v\ne0$. Then
$$
\lambda Bv=B(\lambda v)=B(ABv)=BA(Bv)
$$
so $\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue of $BA$, provided $Bv\ne0$; but $Bv=0$ means also $ABv=0$, against $\lambda\ne0$.

Thus $AB$ and $BA$ have the same nonzero eigenvalues (and, in particular, the same trace). Can you compute the eigenvalues of $BA$?