# If I know $AB$, how can I calculate $BA$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

> Let $A∈\mathscr{M}_{3×2}(\mathbb{R})$ and $B∈\mathscr{M}_{2\times3}(\mathbb{R})$ be matrices satisfying
>   $AB =\begin{bmatrix}
> 8 &2 &−2\\
> 2 &5 &4\\
> −2 &4& 5
> \end{bmatrix}$. Calculate $BA$. (Golan, *The Linear Algebra a Beginning Graduate Student Ought to Know*, Exercise 426.)

Maybe it can be solved by solving a system of equations, but I think there is a shorter way since this problem was in my exam.

Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. What are your thoughts, what have you tried, why do you think this is soluble, insights...?

Comment: I think it can be solved by a symtem of equations, but I think there is a shorter way.

Comment: @José you will have 12 variables and 9 constraints for the system of equations

Comment: Easier question, some ideas for a general answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/731349/16192

Comment: Maybe the fact that the matrix is symetric can be used for something

Comment: We could find **some** suitable $A,B$ by finding the eigenvector decomposition

Comment: It might help to note that $AB$ has the same rank as $BA$, and that $AB$ has the same non-zero eigenvalues as $BA$.

Answer (score 6):

$(AB)^2=9(AB)\Rightarrow(BA)^3=9(BA)^2\Rightarrow \mu_{BA}(X)\mid X^2(X-9)$

$P_{AB}(X)=X(X-9)^2\Rightarrow P_{BA}(X)=(X-9)^2\Rightarrow\mu_{BA}(X)\mid (X-9)^2$

Conclusion: $\mu_{BA}(X)=X-9$, so $BA=9I_2$.

(Here $\mu_X$, respectively $P_X$ stands for the minimal polynomial, respectively the characteristic polynomial of a square matrix $X$.)

Comment: nice work. you got it with minimal computation(+1).

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to explain the implication $P_{AB}(X)=X(X-9)^2\Rightarrow P_{BA}(X)=(X-9)^2$ a little. I thought maybe you were using the fact that $AB$ and $BA$ have the same nonzero eigenvalues but, at a glance, I don't see how that's enough.

Comment: @MikeF You can find a proof [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial#Characteristic_polynomial_of_a_product_of_two_matrices) or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/311362).

Comment: @MikeF More precisely, $AB$ and $BA$ in general have the same *multiset* of nonzero eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** I'll consider the same problem assuming, instead, that
\begin{align}
A\text{ is }3 \times 2 && B \text{ is } 2 \times 3 && AB = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}

- Since $AB$ has rank $2$, and $A$ is $2 \times 3$, the rank of $A$ must also be $2$. In fact, the column space of $A$ must equal the column space of $AB$. So, $A$ has the form
  $A=\begin{bmatrix}
  * & * \\
  * & * \\
  0 & 0 \\
  \end{bmatrix}$
  for some undetermined $2 \times 2$ invertible matrix.
- For similar reasons, the null space of $B$ must equal that of $AB$. So, $B$ has the form
  $B=\begin{bmatrix}
  * & * & 0 \\
  * & * & 0 \\
  \end{bmatrix}$
  for some undetermined invertible matrix.
- From the equation $AB = \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  \end{bmatrix}$, we see that the undetermined $2 \times 2$ matrices are inverses of one another. Given this, one checks that $BA = \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 \\
  \end{bmatrix}$

---

**Remark:** For the original unmodified problem, note that, since $AB$ is symmetric, it is diagonalizable (even orthogonally so). Moreover, its diagonal form turns out to be $9$ times projection onto two coordinates. Let $U$ be an invertible $3 \times 3$ matrix with $$UABU^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
9 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 9 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}.$$ Apply the above argument to $A_1 = UA$ and $B_2 = BU^{-1}$ in order to compute $B_2A_2 = BA$.

Comment: A matrix like $A$ of rank two has not necessary a zero row, so you must perform some elementary transforms in order to get there. I wonder now if these elementary transforms don't interfere with the ones used for $B$ in a wrong way, that is, you have multiply $PAQ$ by $RBS$ with $Q\ne R^{-1}$.

Comment: I have raised objections on the argument of your post. This comment has nothing to do with my concern.

Comment: @user26857: OK I have deleted my last comment, which did not address your concern. I didn't think it was necessary to perform any elementary row operations on $A$. Is it to one of these assertions that you are objecting? (1) $col(A) = col(AB)$ so that $col(A) = \{ (x,y,0) : x,y \in \mathbb{R}\}$. (2) Since $col(A) =  \{ (x,y,0) : x,y \in \mathbb{R}\}$, $A$ has the form
$A=\begin{bmatrix}
* & * \\
* & * \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$
for some undetermined $2 \times 2$ invertible matrix.

Comment: I see it now. It would have been useful to include your first comment into the answer.

Comment: @user26857: OK I have added something to that effect. I was trying to just leave a hint, but I think you may be right that the hint was too vague.